# is curvilinear motion really a type of linear motion?

Tags: particle-physics, rotational-kinematics, degrees-of-freedom

Let us consider any arbitrary curve except a straight line in the Cartesian coordinates. From the perspective of the particle tracing the curve the motion can only be linear. But from the point of view of an observer in the Cartesian frame, 2 coordinates are needed to specify the motion of the particle. So, can we really call curvilinear motion of a particle as linear or would it be more precise to call it as planar motion? 
The confusion arises not due to the use of different reference frames but due to the fact that a particle has zero rotational DOFs (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry) ) which would imply that a circular motion of the particle about any fixed point is also considered translational rather than rotational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of the particle's reference frame she doesn't follow a curve, she is at rest. From a frame at rest on the lab, the particle's motion is curvilinear (it is unidimensional, but curvilinear though).  If you know the curve you can parametrize it with only one parameter, because it is unidimensional (for instance for some circular motion your can write $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$. The common nomenclature, though is still to call it planar motion, because it occurs along the two dimensions of the plane in the laboratory frame of reference.

Any form of motion by a particle is unidimensional, in the sense that it is a curve if plotted  in space. Regarding the DOF: it is defined in a dynamical system, and is the number of independent parameters that define its configuration. So when talking about degrees of freedom you also need to talk about the dynamics: it is the dynamics that define their number (for instance, if the position in one direction can change independently than that in a different direction (2 DOF in motion on a plane) or if both are constrained to change simultaneously in a correlated way (1 DOF). The one dimensional parametrization of a curve does not tell anything about the degrees of freedom of the dynamical system that generated it.

Comment: Excuse my use of wrong terminology referring to the particle's frame of ref. What I meant by that was the 'curve' itself as the frame of ref. and not the particle as the frame. But are you suggesting that any form of motion by a particle must be unidimensional  if we know the curve, irrespective of the representation of the curve in Euclidean space ?

Comment: Regarding the second part about the Degrees of Freedom of a particle in Cartesian frame, I would like to know the reason about why the particle has 3 DOFs if you can parametrize its motion in terms of a single parameter as you mentioned.

Comment: I extended my answer

Comment: @katipra Yes, this is correct: if you know the curve you can parameterise the motion by a single real number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about terminology of the case, then I'd suggest to call it **'1D motion'** to avoid confusion with true straight. With this terminology it is no matter if trajectory is planar or goes arbitrary in 3D space, or even makes loops.